# how to get date in a specific format in android?

Tags: android, datetime, format

I am trying to get date in January 23,2014 format, I tried below code

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(""EEE, d MMM yyyy");
        String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

but it's returning month name only in 3 letters as for january it's retuning JAN and for wednesday it's returning WED. can anybody tell me that how can I get full month and day name?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem in my projects if you want to get the full name you and use a switch- case or if else statement and check the conditions and get the full name

Answer (score 0):

**"EEEE"** gives [full name of day](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/FulldaynameSimpleDateFormatEEEE.htm).And **"MMMM"** [full name of month](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/FulllengthofmonthnameSimpleDateFormatMMMM.htm).

so use

```
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(""EEEE, d MMMM yyyy");
```